# Do competitive bans eventually "forgive" a player?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In *Counter-Strike: Global Offensive*, I was kicked for doing too much damage to my teammate. This gave me a 30 minute competitive ban. I know that after you get a 30 minute ban, you get a 2 hour ban, then a 24 hour ban, and a 7 day ban.

So after my 30 minute ban, if I don't get another ban for, well, a set amount of time, and then I get another ban, will my ban be a longer ban, or can my ban records be erased?

Comment: In case anyone was wondering, I was banned for killing someone else who was lowering everyone else's health on my team. (Commonly known as a "Griefer")

Comment: Are you sure this ban system isn't specific to that particular server? Regardless, how was the griefer not caught by the same banning system? If possible, you should contact the server admin to make the system more strict. Otherwise, ignore the greifer until they are banned themselves. If the greifer can deal a little damage every round without being banned, might want to consider taking a break from the server until they decide to leave.

Comment: My guess is that the griefer just took a shot or two per person, where as the OP killed a teammate. It makes, scense because small damage can be considered as dmg from a grenade or something.

Comment: @SadlyNot It was on an official Valve Competitive server.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe they are forgiven after 7 total days, although I could be wrong. It makes sense to keep a log of bans on the competitive servers and have then eventually deleted. In my experiences (with teammates walking into my line of fire...repeatedly) I was lifted from the server's ban records and had little more grief.

UPDATE: More info found and posted below. Also this method of banishment applies to all forms of bans, [including cheating, TK's, DC's and  leaving early all are affected by the policy](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1203-WJCV-7019).

> **What happens if I abandon my match?**
>
> Updated: If you abandon a match then Classic Competitive will be unavailable for a period of time. The first abandon has a 30-minute cool down, the second is 2 hours, then 24 hours, and one week. If you haven’t abandoned for a week you would cool down by one level (for example, from 24 hours back to 2 hours).

Taken from [here](http://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/2012/10/5292/) and reconfirmed in the [community](http://steamcommunity.com/app/730/discussions/0/846940248676131922/)

Above information is for Official Valve Servers, Community servers are not a part of valve  and contain their own rules. If you've come here looking how to reverse a ban on a surfing map server and the like, you are in the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks, but do you have a method of confirming/proving this?

Comment: Edited with support

Comment: Edited with more support (apart =/ a part)

Comment: @Bora You could've just said edited a spelling error.

Answer (score 1):

If you get a 30 minute ban and don't get banned again for a week, your next ban will just be a 30 minute ban again, (this is for all the bans) but you can go higher. If you get 15 7-day bans one after another, you will need to wait 15 weeks to get unbanned.