# Duration of bans on Counter Strike: GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

What is the timing of the lowest ban on Counter Strike: GO? And the top ban?
I got banned so many times, for kicking afk and flamer guys, and I dont know why.

Comment: Is this a VAC ban or a server ban?

Comment: Were time bans, I think that were VAC bans

Comment: That isn't very clear.  If they're VAC bans, they're permanent.  If they're a server based ban, it's for as long as the server is set to have you banned, which is determined by the server admin.

Comment: Then it was server bans, how can i reduce the time of the bans?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do competitive bans eventually "forgive" a player?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126946/do-competitive-bans-eventually-forgive-a-player)

Comment: I initially thought it was a duplicate as well, but he is just asking the min-max duration for the normal bans.. of which you can get for kicking players too often now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bans start at 30m and end at 7days. They have a cool down path that can be found in [this question here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126946/do-competitive-bans-eventually-forgive-a-player).

Any action that gives you a ban will follow this pattern, it doesn't matter the reason for it they all count towards the same duration/cooldown flow. It truly sucks right now that so many people are getting banned due to kicking players who are afk or deranking on purposes. I highly recommend you simply report those people as being Griefers (this is an option when you report players now). Its not worth what the ban times can get to.